# PSD to HTML element dimensions

Tags: html, css, psd

I have a designer who designed my site using Photoshop (.psd).

Now i am the one who will convert this to html/css.
In the design, there are icons (images) whose dimension is 70x55 (measured in photoshop ruler)

My question is, when i code these images into html/css, should i be using the following code?

```
<img src="img1.png" width="70px" height="55px"/>
```

Is this how converting psd to html works? following the sizes, spacing, distance on whats on the actual psd designed by the designer?

Im a complete noob on this so any help will be great appreciated.

**-UPDATE -**

By the way, when i am coding this into html/css, i am using a high screen resolution desktop monitor (not the standard monitor laptop screen), i followed all the dimension designed in the psd from images to container divs & dialog boxes (designer has designed dialog boxes).

Now after i finished coding, followed the design (followed what i see on the psd), it looks ok when i view it in a browser with the current big screen i am using. The view i am seeing is the page looks the same in the psd and lot of spaces and not too compact to look. So everything looks good here.

Now when i view it in my friend's laptop with standard monitor screen, the page looks very compact, the images (from psd which i followed the dimensions and coded it in html/css) looks big and some of the elements i coded did not fit on the browser screen. Im sure the reason behind this is because i am using smaller screen.

Now i am wondering, I followed what the designer designed in psd. I followed the distances, dimensions of images, etc... Whos doing wrong here? The designer because he designed the elements in psd which is too big for smaller monitor screen? or me who does not know something or maybe missed something here?

Any guidance would be a big help

Comment: for icons google: "css sprites"

Comment: after your update - the high res screen has nothing to do with the image size. one way to check if you got the right sizes from the psd file is as following: in photoshop make sure the size is set to 100% (bottom left corner from open file) in browser make sure the page is set to view, zoom, normal (on a mac press CMD+0). now you can make a print-screen from the browser and insert it in your psd as top layer. now you can set a transparency to this top layer by pressing the numbers 60 (makes transparency 60%) now move the layer on the right place and look behind it if all the sizes are correct

Comment: hi caramba, just did your suggestion and the image dimensions in the browser and psd are equal. would this mean that the designer has designed the the site in psd  only compatible with larger monitor screen?

Comment: that means that you have done your job right.

Answer (score 1):

Cut out the images using the slice tool in Photoshop and save for web to optimise the images.

The width and height attributes on an image aren't necessary although they save the browser a small amount of time reading the images to work out the dimensions. Use CSS to control the size of the image; but obviously you should avoid stretching the image larger than its native size or it will become pixelated.

By default an image will render in a browser at its native size.

Comment: i've updated my post. please have a look. any guidance will be a great help

Comment: To be honest, there's too many variables above to give a simple answer. I think you need to do some reading into screen resolutions, PPI, etc. As a starting point, read this article on CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/high-dpi-monitors-resolution-independance-the-web-and-you/

Comment: Paul, thanks for quick answer. Now i understand about this dependency on monitor screen. Anyway, just for clarification sake, based on what you've understand from my updated post, my opinion would be the designer has designed the the site in psd which is only compatible with larger monitor screen, thats why when i view it in smaller screen, it looks too big. What do u think?

Comment: It depends. The most common desktop size websites are between 960px - 1200px across. If the design is much wider than this then yes, it would be advisable to get the design to reduce the width.

Comment: Paul, ive checked on the psd design and the whole page width is 1200px. We followed every dimensions as ive mentioned in my post but when we view it in smaller screen monitor, it looks bigger. So i assume that the designer has designed the site compatible with larger screen. Am i correct?